# XDocument insert XML data into SQL using Linq and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Currently the two below functions work.  The first one is reading an XML table of NFL PLayers and converts that XML data into a bunch of players (var players), then the second function takes the data from the first function and sends them into a table I have created with EF6 and updates the database.  My question is, is there a better way to do this?

```
var players = from p in X.Descendants("FantasyPlayer") select new
{
    id = p.Element("PlayerID").Value,
    firstname = p.Element("Name").Value,
    team = p.Element("Team,").Value
};

foreach (var p in players)
{
    var nflplayer = new NFLPlayer();
    nflplayer.ID = Convert.ToInt32(p.id);
    nflplayer.FirstName = p.firstname;
    nflplayer.Team = p.team;
    db.NFLPlayers.Add(nflplayer);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

I feel like there should be a way to do this all in one step but havent been able to figure it out yet....IF anyone can suggest a better way or alternate way of doing this I am listening.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking us to do a code review on working code. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would possibly be a better fit, but make sure to review their help center before asking.

Comment: Oh good point theB, didnt realize there was a section for code review.  Its fine to close it.  How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
           foreach(var player in X.Descendants("FantasyPlayer"))
            {
                var nflplayer = new NFLPlayer() {
                   ID = Convert.ToInt32(player.id),
                   FirstName = player.firstname,
                   Team = player.team
                });
                db.NFLPlayers.Add(nflplayer);
            }
```

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I was ableto make it work as follows:

Comment: ID = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("PlayerID").Value),

Answer (score 0):

You are bounded with two things:
1. Initial data is in xml format
2. Data must be saved in format provided by database schema

So I see at least three steps in this task:
1. Read initial data
2. Prepare data for saving to database (convert from xml to database model)
3. Save to database

Your current logic is exactly what you need to do based on the specification.

So now you can only optimize your code if you want to do it.